# Removing group header after pandas aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following:

```
In [20]: df.groupby("dummy").agg({"returns": [np.mean, np.sum]})
Out[20]: 
        returns          
            sum      mean

dummy                    
1      0.285833  0.028583
```

How do I remove the "returns" header?  So that I have a dataframe with columns 'sum' and 'mean'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even to remove the level after grouping if you can avoid creating it in the first place. Call `agg` on your column of interest -

```
df.groupby("dummy")['returns'].agg(['mean', 'sum'])
```

---

**Demo**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy':[1, 1, 2, 2], 'returns' : [50, 50, 100, 200]})
df
   dummy  returns
0      1       50
1      1       50
2      2      100
3      2      200

df.groupby("dummy")['returns'].agg(['mean', 'sum'])

       mean  sum
dummy           
1        50  100
2       150  300
```

Alternatively, using numpy's functions -

```
df.groupby("dummy")['returns'].agg([np.mean, np.sum])

       mean  sum
dummy           
1        50  100
2       150  300
```

Answer (score 7):

Use -

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

To drop the top column level

Comment: This should be the correct answer to the question.

Comment: This really helped when so many other answers did not, that's for sure, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

```
result = df.groupby("dummy").agg({"returns": [np.mean, np.sum]})
result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1)
```